# How to find the mean of values in an array in Scala - Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an array of values as shown below:

```
scala> number.take(5)

res1: Array[Any] = Array(908.76, 901.74, 83.71, 39.36, 234.64)
```

I need to find the mean value of the array using RDD method.

I have tried using number.mean() method but it keeps giving me following error:

```
error: could not find implicit value for parameter num: Numeric[Any]
```

I am new to Spark, please provide some suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What is `number` here? It would be better to change it to not return/contain `Any` type and instead have doubles directly.

Answer (score 2):

That's not Spark related. Compiler gives you a hint - there is no .mean() method for Array[Any] because it requires that elements of Array must be Numeric.

It means that it would work if it was an Array of Double or Ints.

`number.take(5)` returned Array[Any] because somewhere above it you provided no guarantee that Array will contain only Numeric elements.

If you can't provide that guarantee, then you have to map over that array and explicitly cast all these values to Double or other Numeric type of your choice.

```scala
implicit class AnyExtended(value: Any) {
  def toDoubleO: Option[Double] = {
    Try(value.toDouble).toOption
  }
}

val array: Array[Double] = number.take(5).flatMap(_.toDoubleO)
val mean: Double = array.mean
```

Note that instead of using basic `.toDouble` I've written implicit extension because `.toDouble` can fail and throw an exception. Instead, we can wrap that into Try and turn into `Option` - in case of exception we'll get `None` and this value will be skipped from computation of the mean due to `flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to convert to a DF, then spark will do this for you with minimal effort.

```scala
val number = List(908.76, 901.74, 83.71, 39.36, 234.64)
val numberRDD = sc.parallelize(number)
numberRDD.toDF("x").agg(avg(col("x")))
res1.show
```

This will produce the answer 433.642

Comment: @natg If any of these answers has helped you, could you please accept one of them as the answer and "up vote" it. Simply click the little grey "check mark" next to the answer that you think has helped you the most.